# ArrayFormula to find last nonblank cell in a row

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Every row between E and J has one non-blank value. I want to grab that last non-blank part number on each row.

[image: First picture]

[image: Second picture]

I have the formula that could work now, but it does not apply to every new entered data and I have to manually adjust it all the time.

Comment: Please embed the images into the question rather than links that may break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data starts in row 2, give this a try (in cell R2 I assume):

```
=ArrayFormula(regexextract(trim(E2:E&" "&F2:F&" "&G2:G&" "&H2:H&" "&I2:I&" "&J2:J),"[^\s]*$"))
```

Comment: oh my god it totally works! Thank you so much you are the life saver!